# MYSQL INET_ATON. Did I find a bug or is this known?

Tags: mysql, inet-aton

Is this a known problem?

```
select * from 'tablename' where INET_ATON('any valid ip');
```

Shows the entire db. I accidentally forget to add `ipaddress = INET_ATON('ip');` and cganged the entire db.

Comment: You "changed the entire db" with a different query afterwards though, right? Or as if this was part of a subquery that ended up selecting everything?

Comment: `WHERE INET_ATON('any valid ip')`.  MySQL will try to convert this to a boolean.  Since it's greater than `0`, it's like if you did `WHERE TRUE` or (`WHERE 1`).  That's why it selected all rows.  This query alone won't update anything.  Did you run an `UPDATE` query?

Comment: update 'tablename' set field1 = '0', field2 = '0', field3 = '0' where INET_ATON('any ip');

Comment: @user2561395: Yep.  There ya go.  `where INET_ATON('any ip')` selected all rows, since it's converted to a boolean, and therefore `TRUE` :-)

Comment: Maybe important to note, the ip must be valid or `INET_ATON();` will return null, which would select nothing in that case.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I have just learned a lesson the hard way.

Comment: That is correct. It just needs to be in the format of x.x.x.x

Comment: As a small aside, `INET_ATON('0.0.0.0')` is zero and thus boolean false.  So, not every valid dotted quad specification would have yielded true for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

What you query with is basically equivalent to:

```
select * from 'tablename' 
where 1
```

The `WHERE` clause is always true, so all table rows are returned.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with all rows returned. INET_ATON will return number > 0 if IP is valid OR NULL if IP is invalid. Which means, it's like issuing query

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE 1
```

(or any other positive number) which will return all rows.